# How to use IN Clause for list of strings or GUID's in Dapper

Tags: dapper

I am trying to write a dapper query for IN clause, but it's not working throwing casting error saying "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'A8B08B50-2930-42DC-9DAA-776AC7810A0A' to data type int." . In below query fleetAsset is Guid converted into string.

```
public IQueryable<MarketTransaction> GetMarketTransactions(int fleetId, int userId, int rowCount)
{
    //Original EF queries which I am trying to convert to Dapper

    //var fleetAsset = (from logicalFleetNode in _context.LogicalFleetNodes
    //                  where logicalFleetNode.LogicalFleetId == fleetId
    //                  select logicalFleetNode.AssetID).ToList();

    ////This query fetches guid of assetprofiles for which user having permissions based on the assets user looking onto fleet
    //var assetProfileIds = (from ap in _context.AssetProfileJoinAccounts
    //                       where fleetAsset.Contains(ap.AssetProfile.AssetID) && ap.AccountId == userId
    //                       select ap.AssetProfileId).ToList();

    var fleetAsset = _context.Database.Connection.Query<string>("SELECT CONVERT(varchar(36),AssetID) from LogicalFleetNodes Where LogicalFleetId=@Fleetid",
        new { fleetId }).AsEnumerable();

    //This query fetches guid of assetprofiles for which user having permissions based on the assets user looking onto fleet
    var sql = String.Format("SELECT TOP(@RowCount) AssetProfileId FROM [AssetProfileJoinAccounts] AS APJA WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT " +
                            "1 AS [C1] FROM  [dbo].[LogicalFleetNodes] AS LFN " +
                            "INNER JOIN [dbo].[AssetProfile] AS AP ON [LFN].[AssetID] = [AP].[AssetID]" +
                                " WHERE ([APJA].[AssetProfileId] = [AP].[ID])  " +
                                " AND ([APJA].[AccountId] = @AccountId AND LogicalFleetId IN @FleetId)))");
    var assetProfileIds = _context.Database.Connection.Query<Guid>(sql, new { AccountId = userId, FleetId = fleetAsset, RowCount=rowCount });
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc, I ran the query formed in SQL server was throwing the same error, I was using the wrong column for IN clause, after using the correct column it worked.

Comment: yeah, I can see how "using the wrong column" could lead to errors...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dapper performs expansion, so *if the data types match*, you should just need to do:

```
LogicalFleetId IN @FleetId
```

(note no parentheses)

Passing in a `FleetId` (typically via an anonymous type like in the question) that is an obvious array or list or similar.

If it isn't working when you remove the parentheses, then there are two questions to ask:

- what is the column type of `LocalFleetId`?
- what is the declared type of the local variable `fleetAsset` (that you are passing in as `FleetId`)?

---

Update: test case showing it working fine:

```
public void GuidIn_SO_24177902()
{
    // invent and populate
    Guid a = Guid.NewGuid(), b = Guid.NewGuid(),
         c = Guid.NewGuid(), d = Guid.NewGuid();
    connection.Execute("create table #foo (i int, g uniqueidentifier)");
    connection.Execute("insert #foo(i,g) values(@i,@g)",
        new[] { new { i = 1, g = a }, new { i = 2, g = b },
        new { i = 3, g = c },new { i = 4, g = d }});

    // check that rows 2&3 yield guids b&c
    var guids = connection.Query<Guid>("select g from #foo where i in (2,3)")
                                                          .ToArray();
    guids.Length.Equals(2);
    guids.Contains(a).Equals(false);
    guids.Contains(b).Equals(true);
    guids.Contains(c).Equals(true);
    guids.Contains(d).Equals(false);

    // in query on the guids
    var rows = connection.Query(
        "select * from #foo where g in @guids order by i", new { guids })
        .Select(row => new { i = (int)row.i, g = (Guid)row.g }).ToArray();
    rows.Length.Equals(2);
    rows[0].i.Equals(2);
    rows[0].g.Equals(b);
    rows[1].i.Equals(3);
    rows[1].g.Equals(c);
}
```

Comment: I tried first with LogicalFleetId IN @FleetId. That also throws the same error.FleetId is a GUID type, I thought that may be causing the issue, so I also tried CONVERT(varchar(36),AssetID) to fetch from the first query & pass it in 2nd dapper query.

Comment: @Deepak btw; by "GUID type", do you mean `uniqueidentifier` ?

Comment: I am using var for fleetAsset so whatever comes out from query, I believe it will be IEnumerable<string> with Convert clause & without that it would be IEnumerable<Guid>. Yes Guid is unique identifier

Comment: @Deepak well... Why are you using convert? Why not just select them as guids in the first place?

Comment: I used it without Convert as well same issue, at some place I read Guid causing the problem so I converted it to string. Important thing to note is the error : "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'A8B08B50-2930-42DC-9DAA-776AC7810A0A' to data type int."

Comment: @Deepak again: stop converting; see the edit which shows it working perfectly happily with `in` and `Guid` / `uniqueidentifier`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55556/discussion-between-deepak-and-marc-gravell).

Comment: +1 **(note no parenthesis)** is very, very important. Thanks for pointing it out here.